# Marginal distribution from a Poisson distribution where intensity is exponentially distributed?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Given that $N$ is Poisson distributed with a random intensity $Y$, the conditional distribution of $(X|Y)$ is defined as, for $n=0,1,\dots$

$$P[N=n|Y=\lambda]=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n\frac{1}{n!}$$

$Y$ is a random variable exponentially distributed with parameter $\theta$.

Find:

1. $P[N=n]$
2. $E[N]$
3. $E[N^2]$

---

I'm struggling to understand exactly how to get these values from a conditional distribution. I'd really appreciate any hints or guidance.

I am familiar with:

$$f_{X|Y}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$ and $$f_Y(x)=\sum f_{X,Y}(x,y)$$

Are these the formulas I should be starting with?

Comment: Rather try $$P(N=n)=\int P(N=n\mid Y=\lambda)f_Y(\lambda)d\lambda,$$ and, naturally, $$E(g(N))=\sum_ng(n)P(N=n).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

1) [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Statement), in particular, the second formula. Note that since $Y$ is continuous, you will use integrals instead of sums.

2 and 3): Use what you get from #1. $N$ is poisson distributed, so use $$\mathbb{E}[g(N)] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)f_N(n)\text{.}$$

Comment: Is this correct for part (1)? $$P[N=n]=\int e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n \frac{1}{n!} \frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}d\lambda$$

Comment: @Taylor Yes. Make sure you integrate over the appropriate interval for $\lambda$.

Comment: So with the constants pulled out, it will be $$\frac{1}{n!\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}} \int e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n d\lambda$$? Do you mind explaining the appropriate interval for $\lambda$?

Comment: @Taylor $Y$ is exponentially distributed, no?

Comment: Yes, it is...how does that impact the bounds?

Comment: @Taylor If $Y$ is exponentially distributed, then what are the bounds for $Y$? $\lambda$, furthermore, is a particular value of $Y$, so any bounds you have on $Y$ will also be the bounds for $\lambda$.